# PHImageManager.default().requestImageForAsset returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, photosframework

There are a few similar questions around this topic, but none of them seem to help me. My sincere apologies if I have missed something.

Here's my code:

```
 func loadImageByAssetID(_ assetID:String!, forSize:CGSize){
    let fetchAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [assetID], options: PHFetchOptions())
    if fetchAssets.count > 0 { //Asset found
        let asset = fetchAssets.firstObject as! PHAsset
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.version = .original
        options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        options.progressHandler = { progress, error, stop, info in
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                print("dict: \(String(describing: info))") //Printing to have more info on error
                self.delegate?.updateProgress(progress)
            }
        }

        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset,
                                              targetSize: forSize,
                                              contentMode: .aspectFit,
                                              options: options,
                                              resultHandler: { image, info in
                                                print("dict: \(String(describing: info))") //Printing to have more info on error
                                                guard let image = image else {
                                                    self.delegate?.imageLoaded(nil)
                                                    return
                                                }
                                                self.delegate?.imageLoaded(image)
        })
    }else{ //Asset not found
        self.delegate?.imageLoaded(nil)
    }
}
```

Now this requestImage often returns nil. Here's the info from progressHandler:

> dict: Optional([AnyHashable("PHImageResultRequestIDKey"): 29, AnyHashable("PHImageResultIsDegradedKey"): 0])

And here's the info from requestImage requestHandler:

> dict: Optional([AnyHashable("PHImageResultRequestIDKey"): 29, AnyHashable("PHImageResultIsDegradedKey"): 0, AnyHashable("PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey"): 10000, AnyHashable("PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey"): 10000, AnyHashable("PHImageErrorKey"): Error Domain=CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=80 "Missing required primary zone" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing required primary zone}, AnyHashable("PHImageResultIsInCloudKey"): 1, AnyHashable("PHImageResultIsPlaceholderKey"): 0])

What is this "Missing required primary zone"? What am I doing wrong? I am using XCode 9 and iOS 11. Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: If you are asking about "Privacy - Photo Library usage Description", then yes, I have. Is there anything else I need to add in info.plist? Thanks!

Comment: try add "Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description"